# Не исполняется программа на fasm

Tags: ассемблер, fasm

Имеется следующий код

```
format PE GUI 4.0

entry Start

include 'win32a.inc'

section '.text' code readable executable

Start:
      push 0
      push text1
      push text2
      push 0
      call MessageBoxA

      push 0
      call ExitProcess




section '.data' data readable writeable

    text1 db 'Hello, world!', 0h
    text2 db 'Hi'           , 0h


section '.idata' import data readable writeable

  library kernel32, 'kernel32.dll',\
      user32, 'user32.dll'

import kernel32,\
    ExitProcess, 'ExitProcess'

import user32,\
    MessageBoxA, 'MessageBoxA'
```

Компилирую последней версией fasm, компиляция проходит успешно, но при попытке запуска ничего не проиходит.

Comment: Адреса функций WinAPI в данном случае должны быть в квадратных скобках. Если посмотрите PEDEMO.ASM в папке с примерами, там именно так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имена API функций нужно обернуть в квадратные скобки (имена в данном случае "хранят" не адреса самих функций, а адреса элементов в таблице импорта, где уже хранятся фактические адреса функций):

```
push 0
push text1
push text2
push 0
call [MessageBoxA]

push 0
call [ExitProcess]
```

Когда вы вызываете функцию по конкретному адресу (например описанную в этом же файле asm), квадратные скобки не нужны.